# How to limit a form field to certain range of number in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two conditions and confused as to should I go with regex or if there is a better rails helper method to do so

What i want to do is

```
field1: to have any number between 1-31
field2: to have any number between 1-5
```

This is to be checked when create action is invoked.

Any guidance is appreciated here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your respective model

```
validates :field1, :inclusion => 1..31, on => :create
validates :field2, :inclusion => 1..5, on => :create
```

HTH